# Module not found error with Python in Docker

Tags: python, docker

My directory structure

```
    .
    |--app
    |   |--__init__.py
    |   |--main.py
    |  
    |
    |--Dockerfile
    |--requirements.txt
```

I can build this and run it fine. But when I add another `*.py` file to my project, like this

```
    .
    |--app
    |   |--__init__.py
    |   |--main.py
    |   |--handler.py
    |
    |--Dockerfile
    |--requirements.txt
```

and I try to import a function from `handler.py` in `main.py`, like this

```py
# main.py
from handler import someFunc
```

then `main.py` gives me a `NoModuelFound` error for `handler.py` . Can someone explain how to fix this (and maybe also explain why this error is happening)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Print out your `sys.path` as one of the first things you do in your application, there's a good chance it's not set in such a way to get easy access to the stuff under `app`.

The [Google style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html) (the one we follow at work (and I at home), and also the ones that have gotten us out of the bad habit of fiddling around with `PYTHONPATH`) have two rules applicable here.

- Use absolute imports; and
- Don't import anything less than a module.

That would involve importing (and using) as follows:

```py
from app import handler
handler.someFunc()
```

If you're not amenable to using those guidelines, you have to figure out *why* `handler` is not available. This could be because it's not imported in the `__init__.py` file (making it a "re-export" on the package level), or possibly you need to reach down to `handler` the same way you have to `main`.

Without more code/info, it's hard to tell how to fix it but my advice is to go the Google way :-)